# Do I have to log in to all my hotmail and live email accounts to prevent their removal or

Tags: email, hotmail

I have all my Hotmail/Live addresses linked so I can operate them all from one browser window.

I know that Microsoft requires us to log in every (6 mos.?) to affirm our interest or they will remove that account.

Since I have my accounts linked, do I have to log in to each of my Hotmail and Live email accounts separately to prevent their removal or will logging into my main program affirm my interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Live Hotmail, customers have four times longer than with MSN Hotmail before their account expires: 120 days of inactivity instead of 30 days.

Any account, even if it's only being accessed through an e-mail client using the POP3 access, is safe from expiration due to inactivity as long as it is being accessed within the given time frame.

(same goes for IM access, I never use my Hotmail account but I'm using MSN via Pidgin or Miranda IM and the account is sound and safe :).

Comment: Hi. If nothing is sent through those other addresses, is the fact that they are being monitored keep them current?

Comment: as i said, i registered an account ages ago to use the MSN protocol for instant messaging and NEVER login or use the account to send or receive emails.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: As i re-read your comments, I feel that they don't really answer my question. I don't use IM. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually using IM (MSN Messenger) only reserves your ID. Hotmail mailboxes does disappear after 30(?) days, but are recreated (empty) once you login into Hotmail again.

Answer (score 0):

I set my Hotmail up to forward all mail to my Gmail.
I've logged into my Hotmail maybe twice in the last 6 months.

It's still alive :S

**EDIT:**
I've had people say you can't get Hotmail to forward to Gmail any more, I set it up a couple years ago and had no trouble at the time. One of my friends claims to have setup the forward recently, I'll ask him how and get back to you.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the only way I'm accessing it frequently is that it's linked to my Xbox Live account.

Comment: Hotmail will not allow sending to gmail.